# How to host wordpress website on Heroku

Tags: wordpress, heroku

I have a WordPress website currently on my local server but I want it to host on Hero for free .I am new to Hero so i don't know much.What are the proper steps I should follow to host it in Hero.I have installed WordPress already in Hero but I don't know how can i move my website there?

Answer (score 3):

This article walks you through it quite well: https://ksylvest.com/posts/2014-05-02/deploying-wordpress-to-heroku

NOTE: I wouldn't recommend running Wordpress on Heroku for free. Heroku free dynos will sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity, making your wordpress site pretty slow if you don't have a lot of users.

Instead: why not host it directly through [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.com/) for free? It's much simpler, and has some benefits you won't get going this route.

Comment: I have already built a WordPress site locally and I want to deploy it on Heroku. Does your provided link gives this information?